# How to integrate Mobile Express CheckOut Paypal in iPhone App

Tags: iphone, paypal, xcode4.5

I want to integrate Mobile Express CheckOut Paypal in my iPhone App. I have gone through the document and sample Code i.e MECL_Pizza_Non_Web sample code also integrate it in my application,But When I run my application I am unable to get drt and token value. This method return me null value.

```
- (void)receivedDeviceReferenceToken:(NSString *)token {
    //store the token for later use

    [ECNetworkHandler sharedInstance].deviceReferenceToken = token;


    //carry on to the review page
    [self reviewOrder:nil];
}
```

Can any one please guide me how to get it, because it required to pass in the url

https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout- mobile&drt=valueFromMobileExpressCheckoutLibrary&token=valueFromSetExpressCheckoutResponse

Answer (score 0):

make sure that App-ID has suitable from PayPal's environment. for example ENV_SANDBOX is APP-80W284485P519543T.

`[[PayPal getPayPalInst] fetchDeviceReferenceTokenWithAppID:@"APP-80W284485P519543T" forEnvironment:ENV_SANDBOX withDelegate:self];`

and you can also check the console when app running.